# Correct way to use .NET MVC DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am quite new to MVC, and at the moment I'm developing my first application, and trying to get my head around it. For a while I have tried to find out the best way to use a DropDownList in MVC.

By that I mean, is it possible to modify a model, or viewmodel property in a way that the view that is strongly typed to it is passed a DropDownList with the desired options?

Basically what I am asking is, what is the best way to populate an MVC DropDownList with data from a db and send it to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list-items in an MVC `DropDownList` (a `<select>` element) are provided by any `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which is provided by your ViewModel or optionally through the ViewData, like so:

#### ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel {
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> ValidTitles { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddCustomer() {
    CustomerViewModel vm = new CustomerViewModel();
    vm.Title = "Mr";
    vm.ValidTitles = new SelectListItem[] { new SelectListItem("Mr", "Mr"), new SelectListItem("Mrs.", "Mrs."), new SelectListItem("Sgt.", "Sgt.") };
    return View( vm );
}
```

#### View file (aspx syntax):

```
<p>Title: <%= Html.DropDownListFor( vm => vm.Title, Model.ValidTitles ) %></p>
```

So if you read and understand my example, you'll see where you should hit the database.

Remember: the ViewModel is an encapsulation of the entire variable-data state of a view passed to the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
Basically what I am asking, what is the best way to populate a mvc dropdownlist with data from a db and send it to the view?
```

It is actually pretty simple,you just need to read the basics of how to use [dropdowns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in MVC.  In a few words:

1. Create a model for passing it to the view, and let the controller build that model from the data incoming from db.
2. Create 2 properties in your model for using them in the dropdownlist, (i.e: `int selectedItem`, `SelectListItem items`)
3. Once in your view, note that there are 2 versions of dropdownlist helpers, the strongly typed and non-strongly typed, you should use the strongly typed always you can, it is better and more consistent.